# Specifying 64-bit alignment

Tags: c++, gcc, alignment

Given a structure definition like

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;
};
```

What's the best (simplest, most reliable and portable) way to specify that it should always be aligned to a 64-bit address, even on a 32-bit build? I'm using C++11 with GCC 4.5.2, and hoping to also support Clang.

Comment: I'm curious; why does it matter what the alignment is on a 32-bit system?  Or, indeed, on a 64-bit system, since that structure would not normally need to be more than 32-bit aligned.

Comment: Once the compilers support it, you can use alignas.

Comment: @JonathanLefler: I would assume to allow for certain automatic sse optimizations. gcc just recently added some __builtin_assume_aligned to tell the compiler that stuff is to be expected to be aligned. Playing with http://gcc.godbolt.org/ examples might give more insight.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: yes, but GCC 4.5.2 (nor even 4.7.0) doesn't. And you'd have to pass a 64-bit aligned type to `alignas`. So which type would you pass?

Comment: Because I'm planning to use low order bits of pointers as tag bits. The typical use case will be 64-bit platform and pointer heavy data structures, giving me three tag bits, but I want to make sure the code still works if compiled 32-bit.

Comment: @rwallace: I vaguely remember that in x86-64 mode the CPU will enforce that the unused bits are zeroed, specifically so that people won't start using them for other purposes and then having their code break when some future revision starts to use (some) of those previously unused bits.

Comment: @janneb: that's true for high bits (40-50-60-ish), not for low ones. Also, when accessing, you mask out the bits you use for other purposes anyway.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `uint64_t` is not required to be 8-aligned, so using that with `alignas` isn't guaranteed to create 8-alignment. But then, as everyone is saying, nothing is, because there's no standard way to specify the alignment requirement of a class.

Comment: @rwallace: by the way, you probably don't care, but in order to have 3 bits to play with you need the type to be 8-aligned. This is different from 64-bit aligned if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, and the rarity of that is why I suspect you don't care.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you say you're using GCC and hoping to support Clang, GCC's `aligned` [attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) should do the trick:

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;
} __attribute__((__aligned__(8))); // aligned to 8-byte (64-bit) boundary
```

Comment: This is not portable.  But then, nothing will be.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I know. It's portable to the two compilers in question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be __attribute__((aligned (8))), according to the doc you linked?

Comment: @D0SBoots: The second paragraph: "You may also specify any one of these attributes with \``__`' preceding and following its keyword. This allows you to use these attributes in header files without being concerned about a possible macro of the same name. For example, you may use `__aligned__` instead of `aligned`."

Comment: Careful! There may be a maximum alignment in your system. Sadly it's probably implemented in the _linker_. You won't therefore get a compile time error, and maybe large alignment requests could be silently aligned on a finer grained boundary. Here be Dragons.

Answer (score 8):

The following is *reasonably* portable, in the sense that it will work on a lot of different implementations, but not all:

```
union foo {
    struct {int a, b, c; } data;
    double padding1;
    long long padding2;
};

static char assert_foo_size[sizeof(foo) % 8 == 0 ? 1 : -1];
```

That will fail to compile unless either:

- the compiler has added some padding to `foo` to bring it to a multiple of 8, which normally would only happen for reason of an alignment requirement, or
- the layout of `foo.data` is extremely strange, or
- one of `long long` and `double` is bigger than 3 ints, and a multiple of 8. Which doesn't necessarily mean it's 8-aligned.

Given that you only need to support 2 compilers though, and clang is fairly gcc-compatible by design, just use the `__attribute__` that works. Only think of doing anything else if you want to write code now that will (hopefully) work on compilers you're not testing on.

C++11 adds `alignof`, which you can test instead of testing the size. It will remove the false positives, but still leave you with some conforming implementations on which the union fails to create the alignment you want, and hence fails to compile. Also, my `sizeof` trick is quite limited, it doesn't help at all if your structure has 4 ints instead of only 3, whereas the same thing with `alignof` does. I don't know what versions of gcc and clang support `alignof`, which is why I didn't use it to start with. I wouldn't have thought it's difficult to do.

By the way, if instances of `foo` are dynamically allocated then things get easier. Firstly, I suspect that glibc or similar `malloc` implementations will 8-align anyway -- if there's a basic type with an 8-byte alignment then `malloc` has to, and I think glibc `malloc` just does always, rather than worrying about whether there is or not on any given platform. Secondly, there's `posix_memalign` to be sure.

Comment: +1 Very nice (without any nasty compiler extensions). One might even make the `data` struct anonymous to get behaviour similar to the OP's original struct.

Comment: Good solution for defined sets of platforms/compilers.  If true portability is your goal, binary compatibility of serialized data should probably not be an additional goal though.

Comment: Why double/long long??? uint64_t can be used more safely, additionally, the padding can be hidden away by using a bit field: `uint64_t : 0;`

Comment: I don't think you can assure 64 bit alignment this way on a 32 bit architecture...

Comment: @Aconcagua: indeed. On a 32 bit architecture that doesn't 8-align either `double` or `long long`, the code will fail to compile. The failure notifies you that you need to do something non-portable instead. Unfortunately the questioner's requirements, "simplest, most reliable and portable", are something of an iron triangle.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `__attribute__((aligned(8))`. However, I found this description only make sure allocated size of structure is multiple of 8 Bytes. It does not make sure start address is the multiple.

For example. I use `__attribute__((aligned(64))`, malloc may return a 64Byte-length structure whose start address is 0xed2030.

If you want start address is aligned, you should use aligned_alloc:
[gcc aligned allocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html). `aligned_alloc(64, sizeof(foo)` will return 0xed2040.

Answer (score 2):

Portable? I don't really know about a really portable way. GCC has `__attribute__((aligned(8)))`, and other compilers may also have equivalents, which you can detect using preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure gcc 4.5.2 is old enough that it doesn't support the standard version yet, but C++11 adds some types specifically to deal with alignment -- `std::aligned_storage` and `std::aligned_union` among other things (see §20.9.7.6 for more details).

Seems to me that the most obvious way to do this would be to use Boost's implementation of `aligned_storage` (or TR1's, if you have that). If you don't want that, I'd still think hard about using the standard version in most of your code, and just write a small implementation of it for your own use until you update to a compiler that implements the standard. Portable code, however, will still look slightly different from most that uses something like `__declspec(align...` or `__attribute__(__aligned__, ...` directly.

In particular, it just gives you a raw buffer of a requested size with a requested alignment. it's then up to you to use something like placement new to create an object of your type in that storage.

For what it's worth, here's a quick stab at an implementation of `aligned_storage` based on gcc's `__attribute__(__aligned__,...` directive:

```
template <std::size_t Len, std::size_t Alignment>
struct aligned_storage {
    typedef struct {
        __attribute__(__aligned__(Alignment)) unsigned char __data[Len];
    } type;
};
```

A quick test program to show how to use this:

```
struct foo {
    int a, b, c;

    void *operator new(size_t, void *in) { return in; }
};

int main() {
    stdx::aligned_storage<sizeof(foo), 8>::type buf;

    foo& f = *new (static_cast<void*>(&buf)) foo();

    int address = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(&f);

    if (address & 0x3 != 0)
        std::cout << "Failed.\n";

    f.~foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, in real use you'd wrap up/hide most of the ugliness I've shown here. If you leave it like this, the price of (theoretical/future) portability is probably excessive.

Answer (score 1):

`[[gnu::aligned(64)]] in c++11 annotation 
        std::atomic <int64_t>  ob [[gnu::aligned(64)]]`