# How to properly resolve increase in pointer alignment with clang?

Tags: c, struct, casting, clang, memory-alignment

Consider the following structs:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t foo;
  uint32_t bar;
} first_struct_t;

typedef struct {
  first_struct_t f;
  uint8_t *p;
  uint8_t buf[];
} second_struct_t;
```

However, later in my code, the following assignment happens:

```
typedef struct {
  first_struct_t *f;
  // ...
} some_struct;

int function_before_foo(some_struct *p) {
  p->f = (second_struct_t *) malloc(sizeof(second_struct_t));
  // ...
}

int function_foo(some_struct *p) {
  second_struct_t *s = (second_struct_t *) p->f;
  // ...
}
```

And it generates the following error due to `-Wcast-align`:

```
'second_struct_t *' increases required alignment from 4 to 8 [-Werror,-Wcast-align]
second_struct_t *s = (second_struct_t *) p->f;
```

A solution is to cast it to a `void *`, but that seems to only mask the problem. What is the cleanest solution to this?

**EDIT:** This only happens with clang and not GCC, regardless of the fact that both compilers are given the `-Wcast-align` flag.

Comment: `some_struct *p` and `struct_second_t *s` are not interchangeable (a pointer to a structure always point to its first member and this is not the case). Do you mean `first_struct_t *s = (first_struct_t *) p->f;`?

Comment: Isn't `p->f` a `first_struct_t`?  Not a `first_struct_t *`?

Comment: You're correct. I fixed the invalid wording.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951039/specifying-64-bit-alignment   Try forcing `first_struct_t` a 8 byte alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume when you have `struct_second_t` you actually meant `second_struct_t`, otherwise your code does not compile.

The problem is that `f` in `some_struct` is a pointer to a `first_struct_t` not a pointer to a `second_struct_t`.

I should add that the cast in `struct_second_t *s = (struct_second_t *) p->f;` is hiding the warning message.  In general if you have to cast one pointer to another you are more often than not going to cause undefined behavior.  This is not always true but is a pretty good guideline.

In response to comment.

First it appears you will not get that warning with gcc for x86 (32 and 64 bit) as there is no alignment requirement for general purpose registers although alignment can improve performance (see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762173/why-does-wcast-align-not-warn-about-cast-from-char-to-int-on-x86) for more info).  As to why clang emits that warning, perhaps because of performance or they do not have the exception as gcc does for x86.

Second what you are trying to accomplish is similar to what the [`container_of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832301/understanding-container-of-macro-in-linux-kernel) macro does in the Linux kernel.  `container_of` is typically defined as:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

In searching the only thing I have found that addresses your issue is [this commit](https://github.com/anatol/tup/commit/59926f270acda489421ea1a48189f15fc208c7f7) to tup that changed their version of `container_of` to include a cast to `void*`.

Basically, I believe the issue is while you know that `p->f` actually points to a `second_struct_t` your compiler does not and therefore issues the warning.  So you can either not do that or cast to `void*`.

Additional:

It seems mozilla address the issue by casting to `void*` as well:

- [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=659546)
- [patch](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/15bfb9729ff3)

Finally, I would recommend looking at `container_of` and using that instead of relying on the fact that the first element of the struct is the other struct.  This way your code is more resilient, if someone else changes the order of the struct members it will still work.  You will have to add a `void*` cast to `container_of` to avoid the warning.  Note that on architectures with alignment issues, you should not have an issue at runtime assuming you always do your type change between child and parent correctly.

Comment: I'm using the `->f` variable to store a pointer to an instance of  `second_struct_t`. Basically it's a cheap way of doing polymorphism. You can use `->f` to access `first_struct_t` and if you know about it, you can gain access to `second_struct_t`. In this case, I know about `second_struct_t` and am willing to cast it that way.